# Can I use sodium metabisulphite and potassium sorbate together before bottling?

Tags: bottling, first-time-brewer, fruit-wine, potassium-meta-bisulfite, potassium-sorbate

I had fermented mango wine weeks back. After a week I did my first racking to remove pulp. The Brix value is not moving down so assuming fermentation is over, I'm planning to bottle it. Initially, after a week, it was very sour then sourness got reduced and it was tasting bitter. Now it tastes flat.

Can I add sweetened, thinned homemade mango juice to give it a flavour?

Also, can I add metabisulfite and sorbate together? I haven't used any of them yet.

If I can use them together how much should I use for approximately 3-3.5 litres of wine with back sweetening?

How should I use them?

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you, but you should! Especially if you sweeten it.

It effectively can kill all the life in a wine, which improves stability.

On the other hand, if you want effervescence, or a small secondary fermentation such as in some ciders/apple wines (malo-lactic "fermentation", actually with bacteria not yeasts!), complete sterilization can be undesirable. But it sounds like not so in your case.

**Warning**

If you decide to backsweeten with something fermentable (mango juice) it's imperative you use meta *and* sorbate, in the appropriate doses. Otherwise, you'll make a huge mess, and it could be dangerous.

Another option is to sweeten with xylitol - which has no aftertaste and is not fermentable (unlike most other sugars). It works a treat if you like a fruit wine just off-dry, but gets less good (and more expensive) the sweeter you want to go in my opinion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add them together.

Use 1/4 teaspoon per five gallons to add 50 ppm.
Can throw juice, metabisulfite, sorbate and bottle.